# Store Manager - Re-index during product import despite setting to false

Tags: importexport, reindex

I am trying to use Store Manager to import changes for 1 attribute on 650 products. Even though the "Reindex product data" is un-checked, Store Manager is STILL trying to re-index after every product is updated.  Is there a global setting that can prevent this issue from occurring?  My Store Manager worked fine until today when my computer was reset to factory settings and all programs re-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install should not cause any settings changes and some kind of re-index, such as the one, responsible for the product reflection in the back-end will still be run, even if the "Reindex product data" option is unchecked. Also, this process depends on the attribute you are making changes to. If you work with Bridge type of connection, you can see the information about index-related fields in Pending data section.